# Looking for direction in database/platform choice before beginning a project

Tags: database, security, web-applications

I am making a web application and am not sure what is the best tech to use. This will be for a cash strapped charity. Ideally, I'd like the software to be as free to cheap as possible. But, there are corners which shouldn't be cut (security).

The site will accept input from users.

The output must be permission based.

Losing control of the information would be beyond disastrous.

I would like for a user to request a filtered sets of data.

I would like to automate finding duplicates, which are allowed in some columns. However, strings that match may in fact not be actual matches, but must be reviewed.

And I would like to facilitate looking for matches manually (as some matches will not be literal matches and would be difficult to predict).

The users will be non-technical, point and click types. So, that may affect security and usability options.

What is the best platform/database/whatever to secure the data and securely deliver the data (or subsets) to users with appropriate permissions.

Comment: I think this is entirely opinion based. There is no best platform for this. My take is, you can take (almost) any tech stack and make it reasonably secure for (almost) any purpose.

Comment: In your opinion, are their environments where it is easier or harder to get it right? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cheapest platform for this would be Linux, however it's entirely up to you to configure it safely.

Containerize what can be and use a whitelist approach rather than a blacklist approach for your input sanitation.

Use prepared statements in you SQL implementation and hash and salt all user passwords.

Use the latest versions and practices for the language you write the application in.

Your question actually is really broad, I'd recommend you check out OWASP ZAP for securing your web application and perhaps even hire a pentester.